# ie7 - display link as image doesn't work

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, image

I have  tag and in side I have images. Idea id that when you click on image, it takes you to link that a tag contains

```
<a href="gallery/">
    <div class="gal_thumb">
        <div class="img_thumb">
            <img src="image/small.jpg" alt="link_image"/>
        </div>

        <div class="gal_title">To gallery</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

works fine on all browsers, but not on IE7
IE7: when I hove the image, it shows the link at bottom left corner the link, bot when i click it it doesn't response until I click on outer  or title.

UPDATE:
Here is my css

```
.gal_thumb {
    float: left;
    width: 156px;
}

.img_thumb {
    float: left;
    height: 122px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    position: relative;
    width: 147px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.img_thumb:hover{
    background: #6E6E6E;
}

.gal_title {
    margin-left: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 147px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your CSS is doing this. You should show it too.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using this pattern:

```
<a href="gallery/">
   <img width="20" height="20" border="1" src="image/small.jpg" alt="link_image"/>
   <div class="gal_title">To gallery</div>
</a>
```

Then use `display:block`, `float:left` and define a width for the `A`-tag.